# I need to parse JSON array and then add some more data to my class

Tags: json, swift

I need to parse JSON array and then add some more data to my class.
I'm using swift 4 and there is new way of parsing JSONs - create struct with matching names.

1. But what if I have class with 10 members, and my JSON contains only
   5 fields - should I create another struct only for that JSON and
   then copy fields to class?
2. How can I add default values, if my JSON missing some fields?

Spend too much time for that simple task, amazing how complicated can be simple things...

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of weird how your struct has 10 properties but in the JSON there is only 5. Are 5 properties enough to create your struct? If yes, then don't create a new struct. *Only create a new struct if the 5 properties in the JSON represents **something else***

The way to use default values is to call `decodeIfPresent`. It will return nil if the key is not there. Use this with the `??` operator and you can set a default value if the key is not there.

```
yourProperty = try container.decodeIfPresent(SomeType.self, forKey: someKey) ?? <some default value>
```

Comment: My class got more fields than JSON, because some of the fields are evaluating later. 
Thanks, will try it.